# Avoid duplicating rows in SQL report

Tags: t-sql

This is the data I need to summarise:

```
  CREATE TABLE yourtable(REF int,Field1 varchar(15),Field2 varchar(15))
  INSERT INTO yourtable VALUES(1,'a','x'),(1,'b','y'),(1,'c','z')
```

I want to report on three fields as above:

My desired output is just to have the distinct value of Ref - in this case, '1' , appear once and the other fields to appear on one line but with the values separated by a comma, so, desired output =

```
  REF    Field 1       Field 2
   1      a,b,c         x,y,z
```

I am using SQL Server 2014 so am unable to use the function STRING_AGG.

Please can you advise how I can get to my desired output?

Many thanks

Comment: Can you please provide an example where there are three records, and one record doesn't have a value in `Field1`

Comment: Thanks for getting back. There will be no examples of this. The three fields will always have values in them.

Comment: and only ever three records?

Comment: alas, no - apologies I thought for the purposes of this question that a simple dataset would suffice rather than overloading the question with values. But there will be reference 2, 3, 4 and so on.

Comment: you want to concatenate values from multiple columns into one. search STRING_AGG if you have sql server 2017+, else search for xml path concatenation

Comment: Thanks George - note my query above re STRING_AGG, where I explicitly mention it. Have a good day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a `FOR XML PATH` trick here to simulate what `STRING_AGG` will more easily do in more recent versions of SQL Server:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    REF,
    STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + t2.Field1
        FROM yourtable t2
        WHERE t2.REF = t1.REF
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') AS [Field 1],
    STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + t2.Field2
        FROM yourtable t2
        WHERE t2.REF = t1.REF
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') AS [Field 2]
FROM yourtable t1;
```

### Demo

Comment: I'd recommend to say "we can use xml path" instead of "we can use stuff", because `stuff`'s role of eating up the first comma seems minor  vs the concatenation-creating clause

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis I agree with your comment, and I also had to look up the syntax...I never used this query in production, so I only know it from Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: That's quite a surprise, your answers are numerous and high quality! Good going!